# how can i get Drop down Selected text mvc

Tags: html, model-view-controller, dropdown, drop

```
$('#selectOptions').change(function() 
{
    var selectOptions = $('#selectOptions option:selected'); 

    if (selectOptions.length > 0) 
    { 
        var resultString = ""; 
        resultString = selectOptions.text(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <select id="selectnumber">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Comment: Hi Vikas, Please add your html code to the question as formatted text and please add more explanations about your code. What part of your code doesnt work? Do you have any bugs or errors? Currently you are just asking us "How can i get selected text" which is not really clear so please elaborate more. Goodluck :D

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.